# Array en orden alfabético tomando en cuenta acentos

Tags: java

Tengo este método para ordenar cadenas, pero cuando uso tíldes no los acomoda bien por ejemplo si pongo María y luego Mario pone a Mario por encima de María. adjunto mi código.

```
public void ordenar(Compa[] compas) {
        Compa aux;
        for (int i = 0; i < compas.length - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < compas.length; j++) {
                if (compas[j] != null) {
                    String minimo = compas[j].getNombreCompañero();
                    if (minimo.compareTo(compas[i].getNombreCompañero()) < 0) {
                        aux = compas[i];
                        compas[i] = compas[j];
                        compas[j] = aux;
                    } // If
                } // If grande
            } // For j
        } // For i
    } // Fin de método
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparar strings basicamente compara el valor ascii de cada char individual hasta encontrar una diferencia. En este caso, el caracter `í` tiene un valor de 160 mientras que el caracter `i` tiene un valor de 105, con lo cual `Mario` va a ir antes que `María`, aunque para nosotros ambas `i` e `í`  deberían ser iguales. La solución pasa por hacer la comparación ***SIN ACENTOS***:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    /*
     * En vez de objetos usaré un array de Strings para hacer el ejemplo más corto
     * Pero es exactamente lo mismo y te debería ser fácil adaptar el código al tuyo.
     */
    String[] names = {"Mario", "María", "Marcos", "Juanito", "Aurora"};
    String aux;
    // He dejado los bucles tal como los tenías tu excepto a la hora de comparar!
    for (int i = 0; i < names.length - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < names.length; j++) {
            // En vez de coger el String tal cual, uso el string que devuelve la función
            String minimo = nombreSinAcentos(names[j]);
            // Igual con el string que le pasas al compareTo()
            if (minimo.compareTo(nombreSinAcentos(names[i])) < 0) {
                aux = names[i];
                names[i] = names[j];
                names[j] = aux;
            }
        }
    }
    
    // Esto ahora imprimirá: [Aurora, Juanito, Marcos, María, Mario]
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(names));
}

/*
 * Esto lo he puesto en función porque es mucho más corto escribir String minimo = nombreSinAcentos(names[j]);
 * que escribir semejante línea enorme cada vez que necesitas un nombre sin acentos!
 * Ahora vamos con el meollo del método, como ves recibe el nombre que quieres *desacentuar*
 * y lo devuelve limpito y listo para ser comparado
 */
public static String nombreSinAcentos(String nombre){
    /*
     * Primero "normalizo" el nombre usando la forma NFD, esto separará los caracteres con acento en dos,
     * por un lado la letra que representan y por otro lado el acento en si mismo "´" (con código ascii 239).
     * A continuación, uso un replaceAll con un regex que buscará símbolos ascii y los sustituirá por
     * nada, basicamente eliminándolos del string. (El regex ni recuerdo de dónde lo saqué, pero
     *  lo vi hace un tiempo por SO)
     */
    return Normalizer.normalize(nombre, Normalizer.Form.NFD)
                .replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "");
}
```

---

He eliminado tus comentarios del código para dejarte solo las explicaciones en ellos, pero por lo demás es tu código con un par de pequeñas modificaciones.

---

Resultado: `[Aurora, Juanito, Marcos, María, Mario]`, con sus acentos y todo!

Cualquier duda, aquí estamos.

Comment: la cosa es que al ordenarlos debo agregarlo a un textarea si elimino el codigo ascii y lo paso al textarea no se verá sin acento?

Comment: es que eso fue lo que entendí al final, no quería ofender ni nada por el estilo, de igual manera te agradezco y muchas gracias por el tiempo que tomaste en dar respuesta a la pregunta.